# AAPT: error: attribute fastforward_increment (aka aplicationid.dev:fastforward_increment) not found

Tags: android, flutter, exoplayer, zoom-sdk, flutter-video-player

[image]

my dependency on pubspec.yaml

```
   chewie: 1.3.0
   flutter_zoom_sdk: ^1.0.0
```

gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0'
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is I have updated zoom SDK to the latest version and upgrade Gradle and expo player version to the latest flutter_zoom_sdk and it works for me.